# Development APNS with Enterprise Distribution Provisioned app

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'd like to distribute a 'test' version of an app internally without having to deal with gathering UDIDs from potential users -- that is, I want to just put the app on a server/dropbox, and have it easily downloaded internally by whoever. I would also like this 'test' version to receive push notifications from the development APNS.

Is it possible to use the development APNS environment with an enterprise Distribution provisioning profile?

The distribution profile has got the following within its entitlements Dict:

```
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>production</string>
```

However, I'd like this particular build to use the development APNS.

Can I simply change that key/value pair? is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not possible. `production` aps-environment means the app would register to the production APNS server, and receive a production device token. That means you can send push notifications to it only via the production APNS server (gateway.push.apple.com) with a production push certificate.

If you want to use the sandbox (development) push environment, your app must be built with a development provisioning profile, which would change the value of aps-environment accordingly.

One way you can distribute a test version of your app internally is to use [TestFlight](https://www.testflightapp.com/) (we used it to distribute a Demo app which was never published to App Store). However, you would have to build the app with an AdHoc provisioning profile, which means the app would work with the production APNS environment.

Is there a special reason you wish to work with the development APNS env?